# Examples of modules over commutative rings with rich structure

Tags: modules, examples-counterexamples

I'm learning the theory of commutative modules, but I am not able to comphrehend the generality of it since my stack of examples is too shallow (I only check a theorem against the $\mathbb{R}$-module $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbb{R}^3$ or the $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$-module $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ or the $\mathbb{Z}$-module lattice points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$).

What are some nice/natural examples of modules over commutative rings with rich structure to keep in mind while learning it?

Comment: There is a collection of examples [started here](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/modules/) including modules over commutative rings. It is in need of expansion.