# Good examples of modules and algebras?

Tags: commutative-algebra, soft-question, modules, algebras

I'm going through Atiyah-Macdonald on my own, and I'm feeling a distinct lack of examples. With rings I can just about get by with quotients of polynomial rings and $\mathbb{Q}$ and so forth. Localizations of $\mathbb{Z}_{\mathfrak{p}}$.

With modules though, I'm very unsure of what a good prototypical example would be. $\mathbb{C}[X]$ as a module over $\mathbb{C}$ feels very tame, since this is an infinite dimensional vector space. On the other hand, eg $\mathbb{C}[x,y] / (x^2,y)$ as a module over $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ feels unweildly, and besides, a quotient seems like a fairly specific kind of module as well. These kinds of arbitrary quotients feel very randomly chosen.

And an algebra, I suppose there's always $\mathbb{C}[X]$ over $\mathbb{C}$ again, but, again this feels like a very easy example.

In topology I feel like I have a strong suite of examples, and even in group theory, there's permutation groups, dihedral groups, matrices, integers mod p additively and multiplicatively, the klein 4 group. I feel I have a reasonably good collection of examples. With modules, I feel much more lost.

What are some good central examples of modules? Which aren't so nice that everything is true of them, but aren't so pathological that they're difficult to think about? And likewise, algebras?

I've seen a duplicate [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3423972/examples-of-modules-over-commutative-rings-with-rich-structure) which wasn't ever answered.

Comment: I guess abelian groups (which are $\mathbb Z$-modules) as well as finitely generated $k$-algebras (take $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ and mod out an ideal) are a good start.

Comment: If you're looking for examples on modules obviously there will be tons. Do you have a specific property looking for? Maybe you want to know how they differ from vector spaces over fields?

Comment: @daruma I'm just thinking of good modules to keep in mind as I read Atiyah-Macdonald. Let's say I try to prove some exercise, and I want to see how it works with a good example module - I'm not sure where to turn to.

Comment: Any ideal is a module and they can be very interesting.  Another class is got by taking any $m\times n$ matrix and think of it as a homomorphism from $A^m\to A^n$ ($A$ the ring in question) and take the quotient. These cover a very large class of interesting modules.

Comment: @Mohan It's good to have classes of examples, but, any particular ideals that are good to look at? For matrices - I haven't seen that construction in commutative algebra. Any particularly interesting commutative modules in that class?

Comment: They contain ALL finitely generated modules over Noetherian rings. So, unless you are more specific, difficult to say.

Comment: @Mohan But this is exactly my struggle. I'm looking for good examples to keep in mind while reading Atiyah-Macdonald. The examples in the book, and many other examples I find, are these very broad generic classes of examples. When I'm looking to prove, to take a random exercise, that under certain conditions, given an algebra $f:A\to B$ and a module $M$ over $A$, $M_B$ is nonzero, I want to try working through an easier example to see why it might be true, what this really means. But I don't have a good example to turn to. And this happens with many many different exercises.

Comment: If I want an example of a non-abelian group, I think $D_4$, or $S_4$. If I want an example of a continuous non-injective function, I think $f(x)=x^2$. If I want an example of a flat $A$ algebra, I don't know what to think. Or an arbitrary module. If I need to work with a maximal ideal, I have $(p) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ or $(2,x)\subseteq \mathbb{Z}[X]$, or the maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_{\mathfrak{2}}$. But if I need a module with (or without) torsion, I don't know what good starter modules to turn to in order to construct an example.

Comment: About your last comment, again, understanding finitely generated abelian groups is a good first step. Flat is the same as torsionfree here and by the structure theorem you know precisely how the modules look like.

Comment: You will probably also be interested in the following MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25004/gaining-intuition-for-how-submodules-behave

Comment: Thank you @Qi Zhu that link is very much what I was looking for! I guess the answer for algebras likely follows the same theme as the module focused question at that link.

Comment: Yes, in particular finitely generated $k$-algebras are mentioned there. I suppose it's always a bit hard when one just starts out with commutative algebra to get a feeling for these algebras, as much of the intuition comes from the geometric aspects (e.g. $k[x,y]/(y^2 - x^2-x^3)$ has a singularity at the origin, called node, etc.) and most of the algebraic terms have a geometric counterpart (e.g. one can get at least some feeling for flatness via geometry).